# convert perl code to php? (2)

Tags: php, perl

This is the perl code ...

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Date;

my $taxon = $ARGV[0]; # Taxonomy identifier of organism.

my $query = "http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/?query=organism:$taxon&format=fasta&include=yes";
my $file = $taxon . '.fasta';

my $agent = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $response = $agent->mirror($query, $file);

if ($response->is_success) {
    my $results = $response->header('X-Total-Results');
    my $release = $response->header('X-UniProt-Release');
    my $date = sprintf("%4d-%02d-%02d", HTTP::Date::parse_date($response->header('Last-Modified')));
    print "Downloaded $results entries of UniProt release $release ($date) to file $file\n";
}
elsif ($response->code == HTTP::Status::RC_NOT_MODIFIED) {
    print "Data for taxon $taxon is up-to-date.\n";
}
else {
    die 'Failed, got ' . $response->status_line .
        ' for ' . $response->request->uri . "\n";
}
```

I have tried converting this to php...
there are still lines of codes that are in errors: in the else if statement..
If you spotted other errors please comment it here...

Here is what I  have tried so far

```
$taxon = $ARGV[0]; # Taxonomy identifier of organism.

$query = "http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/?query=organism:$taxon&format=fasta&include=yes";
$file = $taxon . '.fasta';

$response = $agent->mirror($query, $file);

if ($response->is_success) {
  $results = $response->header('X-Total-Results');
  $release = $response->header('X-UniProt-Release');
  $date = sprintf("%4d-%02d-%02d", date_parse($response->header('Last-Modified')));
  print "Downloaded $results entries of UniProt release $release ($date) to file $file\n";
}
elsif ($response->code == HTTP::Status::RC_NOT_MODIFIED) {
  print "Data for taxon $taxon is up-to-date.\n";
}
else {
  die ('Failed, got ' . $response->status_line .
    ' for ' . $response->request->uri . "\n");
}
```

Comment: Umm, you'll need to find comparable PHP libraries to replace the ones used by the Perl code.  This line `HTTP::Status::RC_NOT_MODIFIED` makes no sense to PHP.

Comment: @quickshiftin This is `304 Not Modified`. With a library you can parse it. See my answer.

Comment: thanks for that.. I am still searching to replace that

Comment: @Shiplu I was just saying w/o finding a comparable PHP library it makes no sense, basically the code as written needs revision.  Your answer is awesome though, I don't know but the tiniest bit of Perl so out of my scope :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this [WebGet](https://github.com/shiplu/dxtool/blob/master/WebGet.php) class.

```
require("WebGet.php");
$taxon = $argv[0];
$agent = new WebGet();
$agent->useCache = true;
$agent->cacheLocation = '/tmp';
touch('cookie.txt');
$agent->cookieFile = 'cookie.txt';


$query = "http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/?query=organism:$taxon&format=fasta&include=yes";
$file = $taxon . '.fasta';

$agent->requestContent($query);

if($agent->responseStatusCode==200){
    $results = $agent->responseHeaders[strtoupper('X-Total-Results')];
    $release = $agent->responseHeaders[strtoupper('X-UniProt-Release')];
    $date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($agent->responseHeaders[strtoupper('Last-Modified')]));
    print "Downloaded $results entries of UniProt release $release ($date) to file $file\n";
} // 304 Not Modified
elseif($agent->responseStatusCode==304){
    print "Data for taxon $taxon is up-to-date.\n";
}else{
    die ('Failed, got ' . $agent->responseStatusLine .
    " for uniprot/?query=organism:$taxon&format=fasta&include=yes\n");
}
```

Comment: i still have errors, may you help me with this

Comment: $taxon = $argv[0];  --> Notice: Undefined variable: argv

Comment: touch('/tmp/cookie.txt');  --> Warning: touch() [function.touch]: Unable to create file /tmp/cookie

Comment: $ch = curl_init();  -->Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init()

Comment: @ansherina You need to install `php5-curl` package to get `curl_init()`.  For `touch`, create a file `cookie.txt` in the same directory where this script resides then change all `/tmp/cookie.txt` to `cookie.txt`. Also remove `touch` line. For `$argv[0]`, Run this program with a parameter. The perl program ran same way. You have to run this program from Console to get `$argv` working! If its web Use `$_POST` or `$_GET` to get parameter.

Comment: does cookie.txt empty? no codes at all in this file?

Comment: i tried this line $taxon = $_GET[0]; and still has error: Undefined offset: 0

Comment: `cookie.txt` should be writable. And leave it that. I think you need to learn PHP first. For $argv[0], Run this program with a parameter. The perl program ran same way. You have to run this program from Console to get $argv working. Dont you know remember how the perl program runs?

Comment: i only know about php a little..

Answer (score 3):

I don't belive you can use `elsif` in php, try `else if` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The reason elsif fails is because it needs to be elseif.

Comment: yeah sorry for that.. I have changed it but still it has an error..

Comment: I think this line HTTP::Status::RC_NOT_MODIFIED has something wrong in it or it is not right way to code in php i guess

Comment: Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/book.http.php - that details the PHP HTTP library. If you understand Perl, I imagine digging out the correct PHP function should be fairly straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

Where are you running this script? `$ARGV` is what perl uses in the command line. If you're getting information form a form, use the Post or Get methods (accessed with `$_POST` and `$_GET`).

Replace `elsif` with `elseif`.

You call things like `$agent->mirror`, but they're not defined here.

As quickshiftin noted, you can't reference Perl libraries - you'll have to find PHP equivalents.

Comment: @ansherina You're welcome! If you find an answer helpful, remember to mark the answer with the check or an upvote.

Comment: ahwst.. so sorry, I am new to this.. haha.

Comment: @ansherina We're all beginners at something.

Comment: I have searched and found out that $argv is included in predefined variable in php

Comment: @ansherina: Yes, but it's only usable when using php in the command-line. That's why I was asking you where you were running the script. The web browser is far more common.

Answer (score 1):

The following tutorial might be useful:
http://www.cs.wcupa.edu/~rkline/perl2php/